# While calling Modal Popup Extender the rest of the form gets cleared on cancel event

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I need to use **ModalPopupExtender** for the main form to display a subform.
I need to trick the **ModalPopupExtender** without linking to button event hence used a hidden field as **TargetControlID** and **PopupControlId**

I have a submit button in the main form, when i click on it it first displays the Panel (subform) using the **ModalPopupExtender** (which also has cancel button in it).
I call the modalscreen by using **Show()** function.
The problem happens as soon as i click on Cancel button in the Modal Form to Hide the form, the rest of the values filled in the main form get erased.
Also other thing which I noticed if I use the **ModalPopupExtender** without Show & Hide function and link it to some temporary button click event, it works as expected and the values in the main form don't get erased. Can anyone help how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cancel button is causing postback.If you are using asp:button then change it to normal html button below

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="popup" CssClass="panelStyle">
    <input type="button" id="btnCancel" onclick="Cancel()" value="Cancel" />
</asp:Panel>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Cancel() {
        $find("modalBehavior").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @geek I found the error. For some controls the values was getting cleared , the original value of the AutoPostBack was set to True in design view. Setting it to false resolved the issue.